# Java weird Integer.parseInt issue (new to java)

Tags: java, string, concatenation, tostring, parseint

Hello I want to string concatenate two numbers as in the code below:

```
tmp2 = Integer.toString(preresult) + tmp2.substring(2, tmp2.length());
```

Tmp2 is a string declared from before. Preresult is a integer that contains a number. If I print this line it adds the two values instead of string concatenation.

If I change Integer.toString(preresult) to for example Integer.toString(5) it string concatenates as I would like it to do. But having Integer.toString(preresult) it adds the two numbers instead of  string concatenating.

The code for preresult :

```
preresult = Integer.parseInt(tmp2.substring(0, 1)) + Integer.parseInt(tmp2.substring(1, 2));
```

//It picks numbers from tmp2 and adds them together. If I print preresult it gives me a int (for example 9)

Once again please help me concatenate these two strings instead of adding them:

```
tmp2 = Integer.toString(preresult) + tmp2.substring(2, tmp2.length());
```

New to java please mercy :)

Comment: The expression `Integer.toString(preresult) + tmp2.substring(2, tmp2.length())` will most certainly *concatenate* *`String`s* and *not* sum numbers. Please provide a complete example that explains, what makes you think that there is arithmetics involved here.

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. I've tried printing before and after tmp2 = Integer.toString(preresult) + tmp2.substring(2, tmp2.length());. It does not concatenate the values instead it adds them. As i said earlier if i change interger.toString(preresult) to maybe Integer.toString(6) it concatenates them.

Comment: *It does not concatenate the values instead it adds them.* Now that's just a claim that cannot be true. We would like to help you figuring out, how you get to that conclusion. But in order to do so, we need some more insight. Please provide more than just code snippets. Edit your question and provide one whole `main` method you used for testing, including many `System.out.println` calls in order to print intermediate results and show us, which values those `println` calls print out. That is something we could work with.

Comment: What is the output for the `println(tmp2);`, before and after the "concatenation line"?

Comment: No problem, we like helping other with programming questions. But, please, provide a *short*, *complete* and *self-contained* example next time. At first, you provided only 1 line. That way we couldn't see the relevant part (because it wasn't there). Then you went to the other extreme and gave us the whole class, which is too much irrelevant code and doesn't isolate the code (we don't know, who calls it and how). If possible, try to reproduce your problem in an example as one single, short `main` method and that contains `println` calls, what they print and what you expected them to print.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Will follow it next time. And thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line you are giving us *does* concatenate the `String`s, but maybe you got confused because the line before sums them:

```
// tmp2 == "45" (taken from your comment)

preresult = Integer.parseInt(tmp2.substring(0, 1)) + Integer.parseInt(tmp2.substring(1, 2));
//                           |------ "4" -------|                     |-------- "5" -----|
//          |--------------- 4 -----------------|    |------------------ 5 --------------|
// preresult == 4 + 5 == 9

println(tmp2); // prints the "45" (unchanged)

tmp2 = Integer.toString(preresult) + tmp2.substring(2, tmp2.length());
//                      |-- 9 --|                     |"45"|
//     |----------- "9" ---------|   |------------- "" -------------|
// tmp2 == "9" + "" == "9"

println(tmp2); // prints "9"
```

So your *first line* sums the two digits 4 and 5, which results in 9. The line you had given us just concatenates that result `"9"` (as `String`) with another empty `String` and therefore keeps the `"9"`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks I got confused. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this type of operation

```
class String1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a = 100;
        int b = 200;
        String s1 = Integer.toString(a);
        String s2 = Integer.toString(b);
        System.out.println(s1+s2);
    }
}
```

Output - 100200